# Is there a Google Chrome extension that makes HISTORY usable?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, history

I find the browsing history in Chrome (5.0.375) to be confusing - is there an extension that treats history the same way it is stored/displayed in Firefox or Safari?

I've read about [Recent History](http://lifehacker.com/5536343/recent-history-gives-chrome-a-better-history), however ideally I'd like something that integrates with Chrome's built in history and doesn't store its own, separate history.

Comment: Got a twitter response from the Recent History developer indicating that its a Chrome API limitation currently: https://twitter.com/umarsheikh/status/17893717260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/phaehjbfndonoealmdlbliedgiabmcdd?hl=en) might solve the problem.

Install the plugin, right click on the history icon near the wrench menu, then select "Options" from the context menu. In the page displayed, select "History2" under "Show History". From now on click the History icon near the wrench menu to open your History. It will show the alternate history, which integrates with the built-in history.

**If you don't feel like installing an extension, just enter "chrome://history2"  in your address bar**

Another extension which you might like is [this one](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cahejgbbfgmlmjgdjlibphdjeldhagkp) which has a similar interface and also opens when you press Ctrl+P

(without quotes)

Comment: How is `chrome://history2` different to `chrome://history`?

Comment: it is different because it uses a different format that some users might prefer.